# UILabel Background Image Disappears on iPhone 5 and below

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm building a calendar app and have a series of UILabels displaying the dates. For any dates that have events, I put a small dot underneath the date by changing the labels background image with the following code:

```
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:newImage];
```

This works fine on iPhone 5s and above, but the images won't display on iPhone 5 or any earlier iPhones.

Could it be an issue with the image sizes I have in Images.xcassets?

I currently have 1x at 40x40, 2x at 80x80, and 3x and 120x120.

Comment: iPhone 5, 5c and 5s all have the same resolution.

Comment: I would recommend you should use NSMutableAttributedString. Make a bigger height UILabel, at top put dates number and at bottom you can put dot so you don't have to use background image. Background image might not give good quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out it had nothing to do with the image sizes. After changing from using colorWithPatternImage to adding a Subview as suggested by @a4arpan, I noticed that the event information (date, time, etc) for dates were also not showing up in the table view underneath the calendar on iPhone 4s's and 5's.

To determine if I should display the dot for dates with events, I was checking if statements, i.e.:

```
if ([label.text == dateOfEvent]...)
```

I missed the fact that these are Strings and it should read as:

```
if ([label.text isEqualToString: dateOfEvent]
```

Once I made the change, it started working on all the available iPhones through the simulator. It's very strange that it was never an issue on the iPhone 5s, 6, etc. simulators, but it became an issue on the 4s and 5.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add a background image to a UILabel, but you can add a UIImageView as a subview to a UILabel.

```
UIImageView *labelBackground = [[UIImageView alloc] 
initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mybg.png"]];
[myLabel addSubview:labelBackground];
```

Comment: The images look much better (not blurry like they were when I used colorWithPatternImage), but they still don't show up on an iPhone 5 or 4s.

Comment: try setting up image with frame UIImageView * image = [UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(<#CGFloat x#>, <#CGFloat y#>, <#CGFloat width#>, <#CGFloat height#>)];

Comment: Not yet. I was able to get the dot centered in the UILable with CGRectMake, but it still won't show up on the smaller phones.

Comment: Looks like it's a different issue than just the images not showing up. On the iPhone 4s and 5, the events for a specific date also won't show up in the table view I placed underneath the calendar when a date with an event is tapped on.

Either way, your answer was very helpful and the images show up much nicer now. Thank you.

Comment: Figured it out @a4arpan - very strange strange. I'll post it as an answer to my question so that the formatting isn't just a block of text.